# php wont get value from url when trying to echo it out

Tags: php

So I have this url:

```
Api.php?action=signup&name=Kalle&email=kalle@hiof.no&password=kalle&studieretning=IT&year=2000
```

To get the name out is it correct to have

```
echo $_POST['name'];
```

Cause in my case this ain't working

Comment: The hyperlink you have are GET methods and you're trying to echo a POST method; undefined index.

Comment: You should also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the querystring (which you are) then data arrives to PHP in the `$_GET` array not the `$_POST` array

So that would be

```
echo $_GET['name'];
```